# Computer Graphics Coordinates with glu (OpenGL)

Tags: java, opengl, coordinate-systems, glu

I am having difficulty figuring out how the coordinate system in glu works, several problems to solve.

```
GLJPanel canvas = new GLJPanel();
frame.setSize(400,600); // Size in pixels of the frame we draw on
frame.getContentPane().add(canvas);

glu.gluOrtho2D(-100.0, 100.0, -200.0, 200.0);

gl.glViewport(100,100,200,300);
```

**If a point has world coordinates (-50,-75), what are its coordinates in the viewport coordinate system?**

and another one (not really specific code):

```
gluOrtho2D(-1.0, 0.0, -1.5, 0.0) and glViewport(0,300,200,300)
gluOrtho2D(0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 1.5) and glViewport(200,0,200,300)
```

**Where would the two truncated genie curves be positioned?**

Now I think I would be able to solve these, but am lost on how the coordinate system works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The world coordinates are arbitrary, and you get to choose them.  In this case, (-50, -75).

The MVP matrix and projection transformation convert these to *clip space coordinates* which vary from (-1, -1, -1) to (+1, +1, +1).  In this case, (-0.5, -0.375).  This conversion is affected by your use of `gluOrtho2D()`, or in more modern programs, the output of the vertex shader.

The viewport coordinates are pixels, from (100, 100) to (300, 400) in this case.  You just scale the clip space coordinates to convert.  The pixel centers are located at half-integer coordinates, so the lower-left pixel of the window is at (0.5, 0.5).  Your point is located at (200, 193.75).  This conversion is affected by the use of `glViewport()`.

I have no idea what a "genie curve" is.

Comment: I have a picture of it upload it just to show when I get a chance. Thank you for explaining.